# Why doesn't this slideshow work in Firefox?

Tags: css

I have created a slideshow that works perfect in Chrome, however, when I open the website in Firefox the slideshow doesn't show up at all. I have tried out some suggestions on solutions I found here on StackOverflow but nothing has worked so far.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Press on 'Run the code snippet' below to see the code in action. If your using Chrome everything should work fine, if Firefox it won't work at all...

```css
.slide-box {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
}
.slide-box .slideshow {
 background-color: #000000;
 width: 100wv;
 height: 100vh;
}
.slide-box .slideshow .background {
 position: absolute; /* For overlapping of page 1*/
 width: 100%;
 height: 90vh;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 0;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 48s linear infinite 0s;
 -moz-animation: imageAnimation 48s linear infinite 0s;
 -o-animation: imageAnimation 48s linear infinite 0s;
 -ms-animation: imageAnimation 48s linear infinite 0s;
 animation: imageAnimation 48s linear infinite 0s; 
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(10%);
 filter: grayscale(10%);
}
.slide-box .slideshow .background:nth-child(1) { 
 background: url(https://images5.alphacoders.com/330/330145.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
.slide-box .slideshow .background:nth-child(2) { 
 background: url(https://hdwallsource.com/img/2014/4/background-wallpaper-22922-23558-hd-wallpapers.jpg) no-repeat center center;  
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 8s;
 -o-animation-delay: 8s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 8s;
 animation-delay: 8s; 
}
.slide-box .slideshow .background:nth-child(3) { 
 background: url(https://www.walldevil.com/wallpapers/a89/wallpapers-backgrounds-scenic-desktop-background-landscape-landscapes-nature-roads-road.jpg) no-repeat center center;  
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 16s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 16s;
 -o-animation-delay: 16s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 16s;
 animation-delay: 16s; 
}
.slide-box .slideshow .background:nth-child(4) { 
 background: url(https://images5.alphacoders.com/330/330145.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
 -o-animation-delay: 24s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
 animation-delay: 24s;
}
.slide-box .slideshow .background:nth-child(5) { 
 background: url(https://hdwallsource.com/img/2014/4/background-wallpaper-22922-23558-hd-wallpapers.jpg) no-repeat center center;  
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 32s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 32s;
 -o-animation-delay: 32s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 32s;
 animation-delay: 32s; 
}
.slide-box .slideshow .background:nth-child(6) { 
 background: url(https://www.walldevil.com/wallpapers/a89/wallpapers-backgrounds-scenic-desktop-background-landscape-landscapes-nature-roads-road.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 40s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 40s;
 -o-animation-delay: 40s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 40s;
 animation-delay: 40s; 
}

/* Animation for the slideshow images */

@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-box">
  <div class="slideshow">
   <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="background"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looking at it in Firefox right now, works fine

Comment: This is weird... I used an online browser and now it's working fine in Firefox, however, not at all that fine in all Chrome browsers. May the problem be that the background images are SVG-files?